# FuelPHP Oil Scaffolding and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, scaffolding, fuelphp

Is there any solution yet to make oil scaffolding (--crud) work with mongodb out of the box? It seems like it should be fairly easy...

Along with that question, I wonder if I can set mongodb as default connection under 'default' - seems like there is not much written about fuelphp and mongodb.

**Update:** This was recently posted as a little workaround:

- http://g33kette.co.uk/blog/?p=152
- http://g33kette.co.uk/blog/?p=168

Comment: This is two separate questions.  Oil does work out of the box - did you follow the userguide?  Not sure about the Mongo question.

Comment: _with mongodb out of the box_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a new oil template for that. You can copy the code in oil/views/scaffolding and there are two existing templates, orm and crud. Make a mongo one if you like and set the code up to work however you like.

Comment: but is there any way to just create crud models and have a lib work with that? i tried various fuel mongo libs and non of them works... i always run into various problems like "Call to undefined method Model_User::forge()" or that it uses the controller instead of the model generating errors like "Controller_User_Collection" class not found (coming FROM the model, which doesnt even make sense) etc.

Comment: Which are these various mongo libs you are using? The core model works just fine (you dont need to generate the code, just use write it yourself). Looks like you MIGHT be trying to use the ODM as well, which is very complicated and has no documentation, but I wasn't expecting people to download it. I write it because I needed it, and its not considered part of the core so... well not my fault!

Comment: right now im using ActiveMongo... there are actually not that many. there are many complicated ones that are completely bloated. would be just nice if there was an option for oil to define the db type that creates models accordingly etc.